# SQL Relational query Help Student Do Sport

Tags: sql

Im doing a test exam where I've gotten stuck on one particular query, in both its SQL code, relational algebra and tuple relational calculus.

here scenario.

I have 3 tables

## Student (reg_no, name, address)

### Heading

## Sport (sportId, title)

## Student_Sport(reg_no,sportId,Year,Capacity)

In Capacity Field values are Captain, Vice Captain, Member

I Want to get list of sport that has no captains.

Any one Help Me?

Comment: NOT EXISTS is a good start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There many ways of doing this. Here are two:

```
SELECT * FROM Sport  s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Student_Sport st WHERE st.sportId = s.sportId AND st.name IN('Captain', 'Vice Captain'))

SELECT * FROM Sport  s
LEFT JOIN Student_Sport st ON st.sportId = s.sportId AND st.Capacity IN('Captain', 'Vice Captain')
WHERE st.sportId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Sport sp, Student_Sport st WHERE
sp.sportId=st.sportId AND st.Capacity IN ('Vice Captain','Member')
```